# What is the difference between "Wide character" set and "Unicode character set"?

Tags: c++, unicode

Today I was reading my favourite C++ Programming book (C++ Primer Plus) and the section which was about variables and character sets in C++,
however I got really confused about Unicode and Wide character set.

Can anyone explain me why we should use wchar_t? and isn't it possible to use Unicode (\u) instead of it?

Comment: You are correct, questions about specific languages are off topic at Programmers, and should be asked stackoverflow. See http://programmers.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

Comment: As I know this is not just about C++ but also almost all languages support Unicode and Wide character set I just want to know what is difference between them and when we should use Unicode and when we should wide character set in programming.

Comment: http://utf8everywhere.org/ , I think is the right answer.  Sadly, many operating system methods (in windows, at least) and languages (C#,Java) try to get by with 16-bit characters, which, I believe is pretty flawed.

Comment: Stack Overflow already has tons of questions about this. It would be worth _searching_ there instead of _asking_ there.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Unicode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode) has *several* encodings, the most widely used being the variable length [UTF-8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8) encoding (on 8 bit bytes, i.e. `char` on most C++ implementations). Hence getting the *n*<sup>th</sup> Unicode character (or [code point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_point)) in an UTF-8 byte string requires iterating on that string (because a single Unicode character can take 1 to 6 bytes). UTF-8 is today very common (e.g. used in most web sites). See [utfeverywhere.org](http://utf8everywhere.org/) suggested by a comment from [Erik Eidt](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/users/63202/erik-eidt). Perhaps use an UTF8 library (like [libunistring](http://www.gnu.org/software/libunistring/) for C or [utf8cpp](http://utfcpp.sourceforge.net/) for C++)

`wchar_t` could be 16 bits -e.g. for [UTF-16](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16)- (but is often 32 bits, and IIRC the 32 bits is required by latest C++14 standard, but I could be wrong), and `wchar_t` might use a non Unicode encoding.

AFAIK, an implementation might provide `char` and `wchar_t` strings without having Unicode (at least for old C++ standards up to C++03).

In the previous century, many incompatible (and Unicode incompatible) character standards and encodings existed, e.g. [EBCDIC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EBCDIC) on mainframes, [KOI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KOI_character_encodings) for cyrillic, etc etc.

Comment: "a single Unicode character can take 1 to 6 bytes" --> I'd expect that to be 1 to 4.  Do you have a Unicode example that is 6 (or 5)?

Comment: As @chux said, I guess the maximum is 4 bytes [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8#Description](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8#Description)

Comment: Ummm, looks **we are wrong** . ["In UTF-8, every code point from 0-127 is stored in a single byte. Only code points 128 and above are stored using 2, 3, in fact, up to 6 bytes."](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2003/10/08/the-absolute-minimum-every-software-developer-absolutely-positively-must-know-about-unicode-and-character-sets-no-excuses/) . And yes how can we represent code points data (4 bytes) + some UTF-8 flag bits (`e.g 110XXXX`) in 4 bytes !!, they have to be more than 4 bytes to contain the code points 4 bytes data + UTF-8 flag bits.

Comment: @Accountantم Do you agree there are about [1114112 code points](http://www.unicode.org/mail-arch/unicode-ml/y2005-m11/0295.html)?  UTF-8 takes [up to 4 bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8#Description).  Perhaps you are thinking of [UTF-8 (1993)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8#History)?

Comment: @chux yes, I agree we *currently* don't have the Unicode code point `FFFFFFFF` yet, but Unicode and UTF-8 are designed to survive. What if we in the future have code points need 4 bytes to store, UTF-8 is going to need more than 4 bytes to encode this code point because of it's additional bit flags.

Comment: @Accountantم Agree that in the _future_ UTF-8 may be changed again to have more than 4 bytes.  Today, UTF-8 uses up to 4 bytes and defines about 1.1 million code points of which 0.3 million are assigned.  UTF-8 could expand to 2 million without needing a 5th byte - yet that would break [UTF-16](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4984103/total-number-of-utf16-characters).  BTW, Extending UTF8 to 6 bytes is good up to 7FFFFFFF, not FFFFFFFF.